# Create a polygon with a list of coordinates gave by QInputDialog in pyqgis console

Tags: qgis, pyqgis

I have a problem when i run this script. It gives me:

> TypeError: QgsGeometry.fromPolygon(unknown-type): argument 1 has unexpected type 'list'

Here is my code:

```
# -*- coding: cp1252 -*-
from qgis.core import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from qgis.PyQt.QtCore import QVariant
from qgis.utils import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import QInputDialog #this is for your dialogs
#
qid = QInputDialog()
canvas = iface.mapCanvas()
#
N=0
X=0
Y=0
input, nba=QInputDialog.getText( qid, "Enter data", "N",
QLineEdit.Normal, "N" )
if nba:
   N=int(input.split()[0])
   print N
list=[]
q=1
while q<=N:
    input, ok= QInputDialog.getText( qid, "Enter data", " X,Y ",
    QLineEdit.Normal, "X" + "," + "Y")
#
    if ok:
        X=float(input.split( "," )[ 0 ])
        print X
        Y=float(input.split( "," )[ 1 ])
        print Y
#        
    print "q",q
    print "N",N
    list.append('QgsPoint('+str(X)+","+str(Y)+')')
    q+=1
## cretae polygone
point=[]
print "Liste:",list
# space of entities
scale=10 
rect = QgsRectangle(float(X)-scale,float(Y)-scale,float(X)+scale,float(Y)+scale)
canvas.setExtent(rect)
pt = QgsPoint(float(Y),float(Y))
canvas.refresh()
# Specify the geometry type
layer = QgsVectorLayer('Polygon?crs=epsg:4326', 'polygon' , 'memory')
prov=layer.dataProvider()
point= ', '.join(list)
point1="["+point+"]"
print 'point:',point1
#
#Point3 = [QgsPoint(100,100), QgsPoint(100,200), QgsPoint(200,200), QgsPoint(200,100)]
feat = QgsFeature()
feat.setGeometry(QgsGeometry.fromPolygon(Point1))
prov.addFeatures([feat])
# Update extent of the layer
layer.updateExtents()
# Add the layer to the Layers panel
QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayers([layer])
```

Comment: QgsGeometry.fromPolygon() takes as argument a list of list. Your variable Point1 should look like `[[QgsPoint(x,y), ..., QgsPoint(x, y)]]`.

Comment: Thank You for your information. I create a list of list, by the problem persist:
'point2:  [[QgsPoint(100.0,100.0), QgsPoint(200.0,100.0), QgsPoint(200.0,200.0), QgsPoint(100.0,200.0)]]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "D:/BDD/Qplus/testePolygone.py", line 56, in <module>
    feat.setGeometry(QgsGeometry.fromPolygon(point2))
TypeError: QgsGeometry.fromPolygon(unknown-type): argument 1 has unexpected type 'unicode'.

Comment: A part of code: layer:                                                                  QgsVectorLayer('Polygon?crs=epsg:4326', 'polygon' , 'memory')
prov=layer.dataProvider()
point= ', '.join(list)
print point
point1="["+point+"]"
print 'point:',point1
point2="["+point1+"]"
print "point2: ",point2
#
feat = QgsFeature()
feat.setGeometry(QgsGeometry.fromPolygon(point2))
prov.addFeatures([feat])
# Update extent of the layer
layer.updateExtents()
# Add the layer to the Layers panel
QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayers([layer])

Comment: To create a list in Python do not use the strings "[" or "]" , but use [] like an operator. `point1 = [[ QgsPoint(...), ...]]` should create what you are looking for.

Comment: but how to add the operator [] to 'point' issue from:1 -Coordinates X and Y and number of angles coming from the dialogue box;2 - 'points' is obtained from [point] but the result is:'[u'QgsPoint (100.0,100.0), QgsPoint (200.0,100.0), QgsPoint (200.0,200.0), QgsPoint (100.0,200.0)']Traceback (most recent call last): File "<input>", line 1, in <module> File "D: /BDD/Qplus/testePolygone.py", line 56, in <module> feat.setGeometry (QgsGeometry.fromPolygon (dots))TypeError: QgsGeometry.fromPolygon (unknown-type): argument 1 has unexpected type 'list' '

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To build polygons from points you have to organize your points as lists. Inner lists represent parts of the polygon, while the complete polygon consists of a list of parts. But this must not be a string, looking like a list of lists when printed, but a list of lists of QgsPoint objects.

Change your line

```
list.append('QgsPoint('+str(X)+","+str(Y)+')')
```

to

```
points = []    
points.append(QgsPoint(X, Y))
```

`list` is a reserved word for a datatype, and you shouldn't use it as name for a variable. `X` and `Y` are already converted to floats in your code. If your polygons do consists of only one part, then create the polygon as follows:

```
polygon = [points]
```

Or if you have more then one part better use this in a loop:

```
polygon = []
polygon.append(points)
```

I haven't copied your name `point1` to be more clear about the contents of the variable. Now you have the list of lists to take as argument for creating the geometry object:

```
feat = QgsFeature()
feat.setGeometry(QgsGeometry.fromPolygon(polygon))
prov.addFeatures([feat])
```

Comment: Thank you for your patience, it's very good and it works.

Comment: Thank you, please consider to upvote the answer

Comment: I like to do it but I have a red message:...votes cast by those, whith less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score.